# Bootstrap data in order to get an estimate of the variance

Tags: time-series, variance, bootstrap

I have a return series of 60 obs. From this returns I compute a non parametric measure.
What is the best way in your opinion to get a consistent estimate of the variance of this measure?

I did it in this way:
I compute a number of X block bootstrap (to take into account of returns dependence) and then for each bootstrap a compute the measure than I get X measure and I compute the variance.
It is correct?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are describing is a form of percentile bootstrap.  This is generally a good way to find the variance of a statistic, including of some complex non-parametric one.  But one of the advantages of percentile bootstrap method is that you can estimate a confidence interval directly, without relying on the variance of the statistic and an assumed distribution.  For example, you can take the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles of your X measures from X bootstrap resamples, to give a 95% confidence interval.

Whether this is the *best* way to estimate the variance of your non-parametric measure we can't tell you without knowing more about the problem and the data.  But it is likely to be a reasonably good way.

Caveat - I don't quite understand the reference in your second paragraph to returns' dependence.

Comment: I've also read that block bootstrap is only consistent (or at least the method you appear to mention is) [when you have stationary procceses](http://arno.unimaas.nl/show.cgi?fid=15555) (some of them don't work propperly even in WSS procceses). For some special kind of non-stationary series, however, [some types of block-bootstrap appears to work well](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0711.4493.pdf).

With all of this in mind, my advice is to check what kind of model better suits your data (e.g. using a PACF). If you are sure of the stationarity of your data, I see no problem on your technique.

Comment: Dear Peter, thank you so much for your reply. I could improve it using your suggestion about confidence interval. Yes, my series is stationary.

Comment: Ahh, I'd missed that this was a time series.  I've added the time series tag.  I would have answered slightly differently knowing that, but @Nesp's comment covers off the issues well.